# How can I click on specific positions in a pygame window?

Tags: python, pygame, position

Say for example I have a square with a width of 100 (int). I want to print something whenever I click inside of it.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 300))
button = pygame.image.load("button.png")
window.blit(button, (50, 50))
pygame.display.flip()

run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if (50, 50) <= pos <= (150, 150):
               print("text...")

    pygame.display.update()
```

It does print something whenever I click between the restricted x axis, however it also shows input if I click on any y coordinate between that x axis, so for example if I click on (100, 100), it works fine, but it also works by clicking on (100, 200), even though I don't want it to. I don't know if my issue has to do with any tuple stuff or something but from my understanding it only reads the x axis limitation and that's the problem.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work as you have it is that you are comparing the values *as tuples*, which use their own rules. `(50, 50) <= pos <= (150, 150)` requires that `pos[0]` is between 50 and 150 inclusive, and it requires that `pos[1]` is at least 50 when `pos[0]` is equal to 50, and that `pos[1]` is no more than 150 when `pos[0]` is equal to 150`. So, yes, "tuple stuff".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this part:

```
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if (50, 50) <= pos <= (150, 150):
               print("text...")
```

To:

```
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if 50 <= pos[0] <= 150 and 50 <= pos[1] <= 150:
               print("text...")
```

Or you can also change it to:

```
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if all(50<=c<=150 for c in pos):
               print("text...")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using pygame, you can just create the rectangle as a

```py
rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
```

Then, when you have pressed the mouse check if it has collided using:

```py
if rect.collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y):
    print("text...")
```

`rect.collidepoint` returns true if the point is inside the rect

Comment: It is a sprite actually but can I use colliderpoint on sprites anyway? That whould be useful to know.

Comment: No, from the documentation(https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html), there is no collidepoint method

Comment: All sprites contain a `Rect` at `sprite.rect`, so you could just use `collidepoint` with that.